# How to find the Sizes of stash repositories

Tags: git, git-stash, bitbucket-server

I am trying to query my stash database to find out all repository ids',repository sizes and project names , but i am not sure which table can get me repository size .Could anyone please help ?

Comment: I think that the repo size is calculated on the fly when you click on the "Retrieve size details" link (in the repo settings).

Answer (score 1):

The information you have asked for is not available in the Stash database as the repositories are stored on the server in the form of binaries. Hope you are aware of the "Repository Size Details" linkbutton available inside the repository settings which will compute the size when we click on it. I presume that you have admin access to the server and database. There was a requirement to compute the sizes of the top 10 repositories in Stash as part of which I developed a shell script. However, I am only pasting the crux here and hope others can improvise on it to suit their needs.

In the Stash server run this command in *your stash-home* repositories path to fetch the top 10 repositories:

```
du -ksm /stash-home/.../.../repositories/* |  sort -n | tail -10
```

This will give the top 10 heaviest repositories in descending sort:

```
1031    /stash-home/.../.../repositories/1732
646     /stash-home/.../.../repositories/132
555     /stash-home/.../.../repositories/1221
449     /stash-home/.../.../repositories/785
324     /stash-home/.../.../repositories/234
320     /stash-home/.../.../repositories/354
292     /stash-home/.../.../repositories/282
282     /stash-home/.../.../repositories/1328
237     /stash-home/.../.../repositories/2810
221     /stash-home/.../.../repositories/263
```

In the above output the first column denotes the size in MB. The second column contains the repository path which also includes the repository id eg: 1732

Now that you have the repository ids, in the Stash database you can run the following query to get the associated project names and repo names:

```
select p.id as projectid, p.project_key, p.name projectname, r.id as repoid,
r.name as reponame from PROJECT p ,REPOSITORY r Where p.ID=r.PROJECT_ID
and r.id in (1732,132,1221,785,234,354,282,1328,2810,263)
```

The size displayed by the du command will give output identical to clicking on "Repository Size Details" in the front end. It will serve well if these two are linked into a shell script to generate a weekly report.

P.S. There is also a [Stash Repo Size Plugin](https://bitbucket.org/cofarrell/stash-repo-size-plugin/downloads?_ga=2.169470247.722905450.1502478974-1505080783.1476273522#download-318851) but not as flexible.